# MySQL query to select from two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a MySQL query that uses two tables.

Table 1 contains a field named "Avail"
Table 2 contains a field named "CompDate"

Both tables contains a fields named "UniqueID"

The query I need should look at table 1 where "Avail" contains "3" and table 2 "CompDate" contains, for example "2013-08-26"

If there is a match run the query.

I have tried many combinations of JOINS with no success. The aim of the query is to copy the returned data in to a new table "$NewTable" which is created prior to running this query.

My example query:

```
mysql_select_db($database_iPin, $conn);
$query_Hist_Temp_Insert = sprintf("INSERT INTO ".$NewTable." ( RecordID,UniqueID,HotelID,Room,AuditBy,AuditorID,LastAudit,Complete,Fail,CompleteDate)
SELECT RecordID,UniqueID,HotelID,Room,AuditBy,AuditorID,LastAudit,Complete,Fail,CompleteDate
FROM RUB_Hist 
WHERE  CompStamp <= '".$FromDate."'");
```

I have not included a JOIN in this example bacause the ones I have tried did not work.

Can anyone see how this can be done. It feels like I have been trying to get this to work for days.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Cheers

I have used the code provided by below:

```
SELECT RUB_Hist.RecordID, RUB_Hist.UniqueID, CompleteDate,CompStamp
FROM RUB_Hist INNER JOIN RUB_Avail
ON RUB_Hist.UniqueID = RUB_Avail.UniqueID
WHERE RUB_Avail.Avail  = '3' AND RUB_Hist.CompStamp <= '2014-01-01'
```

which returns zero, if I remove "AND RUB_Hist.CompStamp <= '2014-01-01'" from the query it returns data.

I have double checked to make sure that RUB_Hist.CompStamp contains record where the date is <= than my test date.

I have cut down on the fields returned for testing.

Comment: "I have not included a JOIN in this example bacause the ones I have tried did not work."  Doh!  SUGGESTION: Update your post, and let's figure out what was wrong with the join!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you told us, this query should be along the lines of what you are looking for.  It does a join between your two tables on the `UniqueID` column, and includes a `WHERE` clause with your two restrictions.

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
Table2 t2
    ON t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID
WHERE t1.Avail = '3' AND t2.CompDate = '2013-08-26'
```

Comment: Hi Tim, many thanks for your very fast reply, see my additional comments I have added to the post.

Comment: There is no data which matches both conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  This is the only explanation which makes sense.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks a very good point. I will sit and put some more thought in to how I can improve my table data. Again many thanks for your time.